# Astana Studio Context Assist with jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, aptana3

Running Aptana Studio 3 "AP3" with jQuery.mobile-1.4.5.css in my project subfolder. I typed a opening div tag then Tab, then AS3 put the closing tag, then I moved the cursor to the opening tag after "v" and hit space and the context menu showed up. Is it expected to see a list of jQuery tag properties along with HTML Core properties already show in the context assist output shown in this image? If yes. How can I get it?  Thanks[image]